# Mysql query decimal output is left aligned

Tags: mysql

This is my query

```
SELECT P.product_name
    ,ID.price
    ,ID.sub_total
FROM invoice_details ID
LEFT JOIN products P ON P.product_no = ID.product_no
WHERE ID.invoice_no = 1;
```

`ID.Price` and `ID.sub_total` datatypes are decimal(10,2) but when I run that query the `ID.price` and `ID.sub_total` are left aligned. I need the output right aligned and as decimal, I tried casting but it didnt work. Please help me to find out the right query to format as decimal right aligned output. - Thanks

Comment: Why do u need it right aligned? Are displaying this results set somewhere in an application?

Comment: I am using this query in scriptcase (php/mysql IDE) and it outputs the decimal values left aligned. I am creating an invoice so decimals must be aligned right.

Comment: The values you receive from the database don't have alignment. It is a feature of whatever is displaying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you are looking left padding.

Try this,

```
SELECT P.product_name
    ,LPAD(ID.price, 150, ' ') AS price
    ,LPAD(ID.sub_total, 150, ' ') AS sub_total
FROM invoice_details ID
LEFT JOIN products P ON P.product_no = ID.product_no
WHERE ID.invoice_no = 1;
```

Hint: [This link](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lpad-function.php) will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You to set the alignment in the control that will display the value. Say you displaying it in an html input control.

```
<input type="text" name="txtsubtotal" value="9.00" style="text-align: right;"/>
```